# extending spring boot loader

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I dont understand the information provided in the README file for spring-boot-loader

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader

what exactly is the purpose of spring boot loader other than it being used internally by spring boot to create the embedded server jar files. Can we tap into this process and load additional jars from filepath to be incldued in the classpath

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 launcher classes (`JarLauncher`, `WarLauncher` and `PropertiesLauncher`). Their purpose is to load resources (.class files etc.) from nested JAR files or JAR files in directories (as opposed to explicitly on the classpath). So, yes, you can tap into that mechanism. In the case of the `[Jar|War]Launcher` the nested paths are fixed (lib/*.jar and lib-provided/*.jar for the WAR case) so you just add extra JARs in those locations if you want more. The `PropertiesLauncher` looks in `lib/` by default, but you can add additional locations by setting an environment variable `LOADER_PATH`or `loader.path` in `application.properties` (colon-separated list of directories).

Comment: i ended up answering instead of commenting on ur answer .. but the question is still open. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any way to add external libraries and properties to WAR Launcher? I mean something like -Dload.path, cause sadly it only works for PropertiesLauncher.

Comment: Yes, it only works for properties launcher, but why is that a problem?

Comment: can PropertiesLauncher handle .war properly?

Comment: I don’t see why not. It’s a generic launcher for zip/jar/exploded archives.